# Bijective on objects implies essentially surjection

Tags: category-theory, functors

On the website nlab looking for examples for essentially surjective functors I found the following affirmartion: any bijective on objects functor is essentially surjective. I can use surjectivity of the functor that leads me to an equality that allows me to get the isomorphism asked on the essential surjective, this way:
Let $F:C\rightarrow D$ be a bijective on objects functor, so for $d\in D$, exists $c\in C$ such that $F(c)=d$, so we can take the identity functor, which is an isomorphism to obtain $F(c)\simeq d$.
My problem is that I can not figure out where to use the injectivity, I am missing something?

Thank you

Comment: Does nlab really say 'bijective on objects functor'? In general, given a category $\mathcal{C}$, the class of objects in $\mathcal{C}$ need not be a set. Having said that, if the classes of objects are sets, a functor which is surjective on objects is essentially surjective. You don't need injectivity to show that.

Comment: @Mathematician42 Everything you say still applies to large categories.

Answer (score 2):

You're not missing anything.  The conclusion holds assuming the functor is just surjective on objects.  Indeed, the entire point of "essentially surjective" is that it is a mild weakening of "surjective on objects" (hence the name).